# Spring : Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Tags: mysql, database, maven, spring-boot, configuration

I want to run my project with active profile 'firza' But it gives me the following error. After searching on google I tried all the possible fixes but nothing worked :| 
Can anybody help me?

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySportsAcademy?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=ivl123
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
#spring.profiles.active=firza
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.ivl.MySportsAcademy.dbconfig.MySportsAcademyMysql57Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
allowed.origins=http://localhost:9000
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool=DEBUG
logging.level.com.reservos=DEBUG
logging.level.com.sendgrid=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug
server.port=3000
```

**application-firza.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySportsAcademy?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
allowed.origins=http://localhost:9000
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool=DEBUG
logging.level.com.reservos=DEBUG
logging.level.com.sendgrid=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug
server.port=3000
admin.email.id=bilal.raza@indusvalleylabs.com
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**Error**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "firza" are currently active).
```

Comment: Add this dependency as well if not already present:  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is missing in application-firza.properties

Comment: @Afridi Already Present

Comment: @Chids  It dosenot make any difference.. error is still there :|

Comment: Add this line on your main application class: @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

Check this: https://www.journaldev.com/13830/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type-none

Comment: Issue is resolved now.. I have placed application.properties class in a folder

Comment: @SFAH what did you do with application.properties exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have application.properties inside of resources folder with required database param

Here is example

```
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://vaquarkhan.com:3307/vk01?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=xyz
spring.datasource.password=xyzwe
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
#spring.datasource.schema=schema.sql
logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG
```

[image]